# Attribute value turning into array unexpectedly when creating object in javascript dojo

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have below function in my dojo class:

```
dojo.declare("someclass", null, {

    getSomeObject: function(id, name, description) {
        console.log("id=", id, ", name=", name, ", description=", description);
        var newObj = {
            "id": id,
            "name": name,
            "description": description
        };
        console.log("newObj=", newObj);
        return newObj;
    }

});
```

This was fine until I upgraded the product I was working on. When I run the code now, somehow inside "newObj", all attribute values are turned into array - i.e. when "123" is passed as id value to function, inside newObj, "id" attribute value is ["123"].

I have tried using different ways to create object - with "new Object()", etc. Nothing seems to help. When I run the same code in the old product, it works as expected!!!

Here is an output from Google Chrome console --

```
id= 5962960 , name= sng2 , description= test
newObj= 
Object
_RI: true
description: Array[1]
id: Array[1]
name: Array[1]
__proto__: Object
```

Any help???

Comment: please show the actual console output of calling that function.  Objects don't just become arrays all by themselves.

Comment: I updated the above question with console output.

Comment: OK, that's pretty weird.  The presence of the `_RI` attribute means that Dojo got its hands on your object _before_ the console log was expanded out.  It's not unknown for expanded objects to show their current state in the console, though, rather than what it was at the time of logging.  Try logging `newObj.id` directly rather than the whole of `newObj`.

Comment: presence of `_RI` simply means that he has logged the `_Root_Item` of his store's items

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are using an `ItemFileReadStore` or `ItemFileWriteStore`.
Then it is absolutely normal, these stores works with arrays internally.
To get the value you should do as recommended in the doc:

```
 store.getValue(storeItem, "property");
```

or if you're certain that value represented in propery, you can safely typecast by doing `+ ""`